# Lead Conversion: Setting the Opportunity Close Date

Tags: lead-conversion

Currently in our Org when a Lead is converted and an Opportunity is created the Close Date on the Opportunity gets set to the end of the current Fiscal quarter...  Is there a way to change this to something like TODAY + 180 ?

Comment: You must have some existing logic in your org that is forcing the close date to end of quarter - have you located where that logic exists?

Comment: I just stepped in as Admin so this is all inherited...  That said: I have looked to see where this is defined, and I can't actually find anything. So maybe some help with where to look would be good.

Comment: 1) look for workflow field updates that set CloseDate; 2) Look through triggers on Lead and Opportunity to see if set there (could be Lead because after update trigger on Lead can manipulate Oppo; could be before insert trigger on Oppo that manipulates as well; triggers may use apex classes to do their work so look deep

Comment: I looked through workflows field updates for both Opps and Leads and don't see anything - As well I looked through the Triggers and the only ones we have were created by two Lead management apps Marketo and DiscoverOrg and none appear to relate to the creation of the Opportunity (!)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the close date to be editable in UI? If yes, you could write a trigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) to have its close date to be set to today + 180. If close date doesn't need to be editable, you could simply designate that field as a formula with your date formula.

Comment: yes but the trigger sb on after insert only and ...must be able to detect lead conversion event which will require mapping a field from Lead to Oppo; if you are going the trigger route, do it on after update in (converted) Lead. However, OP can be solved using workflows

Answer (score 1):

On Lead Conversion, the Opportunity Close Date is automatically set to the end of the fiscal year per the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lead_conversion_mapping.htm&language=en_US) as follows:

> If you are not using custom fiscal years, the Close Date of the newly
> created opportunity is automatically set to the last day of the
> current fiscal quarter.
>
> If you are using custom fiscal years, the
> Close Date is the last day of the current fiscal period. If you are
> using custom fiscal years and a fiscal year has not been defined for
> the current date, the Close Date is the end of the current calendar
> quarter.

(So despite all my comments above, you do not have some custom workflow or trigger that sets it ... sheesh and apologies)

The solution is quite simple ([here is an example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008pKwIAI))

To only do this when you convert a Lead and not when entering an Opportunity via user entry or an API...

1. Create a checkbox formula field on Lead called is_a_lead__c value = true, no need to show in page layout
2. Create a checkbox field on Opportunity called is_sourced_from_lead_conversion__c, default is false - no need to show in page layout
3. In the Lead Field mapping, map `is_a_lead__c` to `is_sourced_from_lead_conversion__c`
4. Add a new Workflow rule on Opportunity which runs `on created` and if `is_sourced_from_lead_conversion__c = true`
5. The Workflow rule uses a field update to set CloseDate to TODAY()+180

Note also the Lead Setting - `Require Validation for Converted Leads`  https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_leadsettings.htm&siteLang=en_US which may impact other things in your lead conversion process